# What's the benefit of installing Ubuntu with a separate /home partition?

Tags: system-installation, home-directory, partitioning

I didn't see anything on here about my question but if this is indeed a dupe, please let me know. I figure this is a simple question but I've never chosen a separate partition for my home directory because of running out of room, I've done it for other directories which made my system feel like it had too many quotas...

- All I wanna know is what are some of the benefits of installing Ubuntu with a separate /home partition?
- What drives users to choose a separate partition for their home directory?
- Are these benefits applicable to other linux and maybe non-linux operating systems?

Thanks!

Comment: Well at least your question survived for two minutes :)

Comment: I've marked your suggested article as a solution and mine as a dupe, thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: +1 for marking your own question as a dupe. Welcome to **Ask Ubuntu**